# Installing older version of AnyLogic or downgrading AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

The newest AnyLogic version is not supported by my current AnyLogic license. The license only supports up to 8.3.3. However, I do wish to install AnyLogic on another computer and activate it with my license. However, surprisingly I could not find downloads of earlier AnyLogic versions. Does anyone know if and where I can find these earlier versions, and whether I perhaps can downgrade a newer AnyLogic version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.3.3.exe

For any version, just put the version you want and you will likely be able to download it

if using mac:
https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.3.3.dmg

Comment: Thanks Felipe. Helpful as always :-)

Comment: For the Free version use ple instead of professional. i.e. https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-ple-8.1.0.exe

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Felipe's answer, you can always ask

> support@anylogic.com

if you need *very* old versions. I believe that AL7.x is not available online anymore but they happily send the installers if you need them.